# Esp8266 Led turn on pin d4

Tags: led, esp8266, pins

I have a led hooked up to pin d4, and strangely for some reason flashes back and fourth when the native led on the esp8226 board is flashing, which is while it is flashing the program. I have the following code which this part is where I am trying to turn the led on

```
GPIO.set_mode(2, GPIO.MODE_OUTPUT);
GPIO.write(2, 1);
```

Now I am assuming that the write command would open the connection and turn the led on, but am not sure. Here is a picture of my setup. What does this command actually do `GPIO.write(2, 1);`

[image: board]

Here is the full code

```
load("api_aws.js");
load("api_azure.js");
load("api_config.js");
load("api_dash.js");
load("api_events.js");
load("api_gcp.js");
load("api_gpio.js");
load("api_mqtt.js");
load("api_shadow.js");
load("api_timer.js");
load("api_sys.js");
load("api_watson.js");

let btn = Cfg.get("board.btn1.pin"); // Built-in button GPIO
let led = Cfg.get("board.led1.pin"); // Built-in LED GPIO number
let onhi = Cfg.get("board.led1.active_high"); // LED on when high?
let state = { on: false, btnCount: 0, uptime: 0 }; // Device state
let online = false; // Connected to the cloud?

let setLED = function (on) {
  let level = onhi ? on : !on;
  GPIO.write(led, level);
  print("LED on ->", on);
};

GPIO.set_mode(2, GPIO.MODE_OUTPUT);

GPIO.write(2, 1);

GPIO.set_mode(led, GPIO.MODE_OUTPUT);
setLED(state.on);

let reportState = function () {
  Shadow.update(0, state);
};

// Update state every second, and report to cloud if online
Timer.set(
  1000,
  Timer.REPEAT,
  function () {
    state.uptime = Sys.uptime();
    state.ram_free = Sys.free_ram();
    print("online:", online, JSON.stringify(state));
    if (online) reportState();
  },
  null
);

// Set up Shadow handler to synchronise device state with the shadow state
Shadow.addHandler(function (event, obj) {
  if (event === "UPDATE_DELTA") {
    print("GOT DELTA:", JSON.stringify(obj));
    for (let key in obj) {
      // Iterate over all keys in delta
      if (key === "on") {
        // We know about the 'on' key. Handle it!
        state.on = obj.on; // Synchronise the state
        setLED(state.on); // according to the delta
      } else if (key === "reboot") {
        state.reboot = obj.reboot; // Reboot button clicked: that
        Timer.set(
          750,
          0,
          function () {
            // incremented 'reboot' counter
            Sys.reboot(500); // Sync and schedule a reboot
          },
          null
        );
      }
    }
    reportState(); // Report our new state, hopefully clearing delta
  }
});

if (btn >= 0) {
  let btnCount = 0;
  let btnPull, btnEdge;
  if (Cfg.get("board.btn1.pull_up") ? GPIO.PULL_UP : GPIO.PULL_DOWN) {
    btnPull = GPIO.PULL_UP;
    btnEdge = GPIO.INT_EDGE_NEG;
  } else {
    btnPull = GPIO.PULL_DOWN;
    btnEdge = GPIO.INT_EDGE_POS;
  }
  GPIO.set_button_handler(
    btn,
    btnPull,
    btnEdge,
    20,
    function () {
      state.btnCount++;
      let newMessage = {
        action: "sendmessage",
        data: "pushed test build flash",
      };
      let message = JSON.stringify(newMessage);
      let sendMQTT = true;
      if (Azure.isConnected()) {
        print("== Sending Azure D2C message:", message);
        Azure.sendD2CMsg("", message);
        sendMQTT = false;
      }
      if (GCP.isConnected()) {
        print("== Sending GCP event:", message);
        GCP.sendEvent(message);
        sendMQTT = false;
      }
      if (Watson.isConnected()) {
        print("== Sending Watson event:", message);
        Watson.sendEventJSON("ev", { d: state });
        sendMQTT = false;
      }
      if (Dash.isConnected()) {
        print("== Click!");
        // TODO: Maybe do something else?
        sendMQTT = false;
      }
      // AWS is handled as plain MQTT since it allows arbitrary topics.
      if (AWS.isConnected() || (MQTT.isConnected() && sendMQTT)) {
        let topic = "devices/" + Cfg.get("device.id") + "/events";
        print("== Publishing to " + topic + ":", message);
        MQTT.pub(topic, message, 0 /* QoS */);
      } else if (sendMQTT) {
        print("== Not connected!");
      }
    },
    null
  );
}

Event.on(
  Event.CLOUD_CONNECTED,
  function () {
    online = true;
    Shadow.update(0, { ram_total: Sys.total_ram() });
  },
  null
);

Event.on(
  Event.CLOUD_DISCONNECTED,
  function () {
    online = false;
  },
  null
);
```

Comment: D4 is also the pin that the internal LED is connected to. The intenal LED will be off when D4 is HIGH (1) and on when it's LOW (0). This explains the behaviour you see. See [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/79223/onboard-led-high-and-low-seems-reversed) (this concerns an ESP32 but the mechanism is the same).

Comment: ok I moved to D5 which is pin 14 and is working now, do you see any issues with that being the clck pin?

Comment: Using D5 is fine unless you want to interface with an SPI device (for which you would need the CLK pin).

Comment: What is a common thing to do when you have multiple functions on a pin, is there a way to detect that in the program and choose one over the other?